# Putting the results of "WITH Queries" into NEW table In PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

How I can put the result of a **(WITH Queries)** in a new table.

The relevant code is:

```
WITH A as (
SELECT ambtemp,dt,
       date_trunc('hour', dt)+
       CASE WHEN date_part('minute', dt) >= 30
            THEN interval '30 minutes'
            ELSE interval '0 minutes'
       END as t
FROM temm),


B as(
SELECT ambtemp,dt,

       max(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp,
       min(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as min_temp
FROM A)



SELECT ambtemp,dt     
FROM B
WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.2
```

Which I need to put the results into a new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use it within a create table statement as any other select:

```
create table foo 
as
with a as (
  ...
), b as ( 
  ...
)
select ambtemp,dt     
from B
where (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.2
```

or, if you already have that table, use it as the source of an insert statement:

```
insert into foo (col1, col2)
with a as (
  ...
), b as ( 
  ...
)
select ambtemp,dt     
from B
where (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.2
```